# Cannot find module 'bitly'

Tags: module

I installed bitly module both local and global. Stil i am getting the error

E:\NodeJS\api-master>npm install -g bitly

```
E:\NodeJS\api-master>node server
```

module.js:538
    throw err;
    ^

```
Error: Cannot find module 'bitly'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:536:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:466:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:579:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\NodeJS\burstsmsapi-master\server.js:18:21)
    at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)

E:\NodeJS\api-master>
```

Comment: I have answered for your question let me know if it works for you.

Comment: unfortunately, i was trying multiple options including reinstalling node. need to check this if I come across again. almost a lost stage now

Comment: Can you share your code? it will be easier for me to test if I have a copy of your code.

Comment: @vasanth _i tried below code_     `const BitlyClient = require('bitly');
const bitly = BitleyClient('<accessToken>');
 
try {
  return await bitly.shorten(uri);
} catch(e) {
  throw e;
}`     as per https://www.npmjs.com/package/bitly. new error is - return await bitly.shorten(uri);
               ^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: Did you find the way to fix this issue, bro?

Answer (score 0):

I think you installed on wrong path.
Check is there functions folder is present in your current directory.If you want to install bitly and deploy firebase function then run this commands.

```
cd functions/
sudo npm install bitly --save
sudo firebase deploy --only functions:YOURFUNCTIONAME
```

Hope this will work.